# Ruby on Rails relationship model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby on Rails 4, how do you create a many-to-many relationship inside a relationship model for a friends list such as Facebook using the `has_many :through ...` syntax ?? I'm a newbie and currently learning Ruby on Rails 4. I have looked at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

But still have a hard time grasping it.

Comment: What models do you want to create the relationship between? The same model or different model?

Answer (score 0):

you will need a join table that references both sides of the relations

let us say you have an relation Post and another relation Category with a many to many relationship between them you need a join table to be able to represent the relationship.

migration for a join table would be

`class CreateCategoriesPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories_posts do |t|
      t.integer :category_id
      t.integer :post_id
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :categories_posts, [:category_id, :post_id]
  end
end`

and in the  models/post.rb

`Class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end`

and in the models/category.rb

`Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end`

more here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 0):

I think @RAF pretty much nailed it. But to use the OP's example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users_list
end

class UsersList < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Although at first it might seem like a User should have only one list of friends (UsersList), that might not always be the case. Think of types within the UserList model, such as: 'close friends', 'work friends', 'all friends' for example.

My advice: dig into the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). This is a concept worth learning and truly understanding (which I'm still doing :).

Comment: Thank you so much AlexanderRD . From your example, I see users_list is a model,which i am guessing would have three columns, users, and friends, and relationship type. I will keep looking at the Rails guide and definitely test out my understanding of what I learn on it on my app.

Answer (score 0):

many-to_many relationships are a simple concept, but complex when using the database because of the way databases work.  A person could have 1 to N different friends, which means that a single entry for a database would need a *dynamic* amount of memory for each entry, which in the db world is a no-no.  So instead of creating a *list* of friends you would have to make a table that represents the *links* between friends, for example:

```
friendship.rb
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :friend, foreign_key: 'friend_A' # this entry has a field called 'friend_A'
  belongs_to :friend, foreign_key: 'friend_B' # this entry has a field called 'friend_B'
end
```

These links will represent your network of friends.  However, as the two previous answers have mentioned, Rails has some nifty magic, "has_and_belongs_to_many", which will do this for you.

Comment: Model.rb
'has_many alphas, through: beta'
 is just a way to tell Rails that 'Model.alphas' means 'Model.beta.alphas'

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE: The problem here is that in my StatusesController, in the index action, the @relationship object only gets the statuses of all your friends, but does not get your own statuses. Is there a better way of approaching this? I am trying to create a view to view all statuses of users that are your friends, and your own statuses too, and so far, I can't seem to figure out how to order it chronologically, even if in my status model, i included "default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) } ". Any advice would be deeply appreciated

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :relationships
  has_many :friends, :through => :relationships

has_many :inverse_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
  has_many :inverse_friends, through: 'inverse_relationships', :source => :user end

#

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base

# before_save...
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'

end

#

class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

def friend_request
    user_id = current_user.id
    friend_id = params[:id]
    if Relationship.where( user_id: user_id, friend_id: friend_id, accepted: false).blank?
      Relationship.create(user_id: user_id, friend_id: friend_id, accepted: false)

```
  redirect_to user_path(params[:id])
else
  redirect_to user_path(params[:id])
end
```

end

def friend_request_accept
    # accepting a friend request is done by the recipient of the friend request.
    # thus the current user is identified by to_id.

```
relationship = Relationship.where(user_id: params[:id], friend_id: current_user.id).first
if Relationship.exists?(relationship) and relationship.accepted == false
  relationship.update_attributes(accepted: true)
end

redirect_to relationships_path
```

end

def friend_request_reject
    relationship = Relationship.where(user_id: params[:id], friend_id: current_user.id).first
    relationship.destroy

```
redirect_to relationships_path
```

end

################################

def index
    @relationships_pending = Relationship.where(friend_id: current_user.id, accepted: false)
  end

end

#

class StatusesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @status = Status.new

@relationship = Relationship.where('friend_id = ? OR user_id = ?', current_user.id, current_user.id).
    where( accepted: true)

end

def new
    @status = Status.new
  end

end

#